# Evaluate mathematical expression containing if else keyword in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mathematical Expression in string:

`'AA*0.16 if ((BB-CC)> AA) else (BB-CC)*0.16'`

Where `AA = 10, BB = 15, CC = 14`

It is possible with `eval`

like `eval('AA*0.16 if ((BB-CC)> AA) else (BB-CC)*0.16',{'AA':10,'BB': 15,'CC':14})`

It gives correct answer but i want alternative for doing this.

Any help appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You can always write your own method.

Comment: Just doing `AA*0.16 if ((BB-CC)> AA) else (BB-CC)*0.16` works fine for me. Your above example returns 0.16 without eval.

Comment: @Loocid It is a string.

Comment: The alternative would be to implement your own specialised parser using, e.g., [tag:pyparsing].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **simpleeval** package:
It is safe version of **eval** and you can modify the level of security of this by overriding the function of if.

```
from simpleeval import simple_eval

simple_eval('AA*0.16 if ((BB-CC)> AA) else (BB-CC)*0.16',names={'AA':10,'BB': 15,'CC':14})
```

For more information, check it out [here.](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/)

Answer (score -2):

You can see the example below.

```
def math_method(AA,BB,CC):
  return AA*0.016 if ((BB-CC)> AA) else (BB-CC)*0.16

print(math_method(10,15,14))
>> 0.16
```

The method returns `AA*0.016` if `(BB-CC) > AA` and will return `(BB-CC)*0.16` otherwise.